# How to find Version of Qt?

Tags: qt4, pyqt, qt-creator, qtcore, qtcpsocket

How do I know which version of Qt I am using? When I open Qt Creator it shows "Welcome to Qt Creator 2.3". In the build setting, however, it shows Qt Version 4.7.1.

Answer (score 74):

```
qmake-qt5 --version
```

or

```
qmake --version
```

Comment: I had to use qmake6 --version in Ubuntu mantic.

Answer (score 51):

Starting with Qt 5.3 you can use:

```
qtdiag
```

This prints a bunch of useful information. The first line includes the version:

```
Qt 5.5.1 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 5.3.1 20160407) on "xcb"
```

Comment: Interesting but OP was for Qt 4 so pyqt 4.x

Comment: on my docker container, this says `qtdiag: could not find a Qt installation of ''
`, but build runs through perfectly. QT5, Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 23):

All the version info is in PyQt5.Qt:

```
import inspect
from PyQt5 import Qt

vers = ['%s = %s' % (k,v) for k,v in vars(Qt).items() if k.lower().find('version') >= 0 and not inspect.isbuiltin(v)]
print('\n'.join(sorted(vers)))
```

prints

```
PYQT_VERSION = 328193
PYQT_VERSION_STR = 5.2.1
QOpenGLVersionProfile = <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QOpenGLVersionProfile'>
QT_VERSION = 328192
QT_VERSION_STR = 5.2.0
qVersion = <built-in function qVersion>
qWebKitMajorVersion = <built-in function qWebKitMajorVersion>
qWebKitMinorVersion = <built-in function qWebKitMinorVersion>
qWebKitVersion = <built-in function qWebKitVersion>
```

The functions can be called too:

```
>>> vers = ['%s = %s' % (k,v()) for k,v in vars(Qt).items() if k.lower().find('version') >= 0 and inspect.isbuiltin(v)]
>>> print('\n'.join(sorted(vers)))
qVersion = 5.2.0
qWebKitMajorVersion = 538
qWebKitMinorVersion = 1
qWebKitVersion = 538.1
```

Comment: Very useful, thank you for sharing your knowledge. Of the ones you wrote about above I use `print("Qt version: " + str(QtCore.qVersion()))` and `print("PyQt (Python module) version: " + str(Qt.PYQT_VERSION_STR))`

Answer (score 8):

You are using Qt version 4.7.1, because that is the version of the qmake.
You can also from shell type qmake -v to get it.
The other version, namely 2.3, is the version of Qt Creator, not of Qt

Comment: Thanks @menzZana , can you tell me how to upgrade qt 4.7.1 to qt 5.2.1

Comment: You can install new Qt version at http://qt-project.org/downloads Also you can add the new Qt directly to your Qt Creator, so it uses the new Qt by going to Tools>Options>Build&Run>Qt version and add the new version in Qt Creator

Comment: My operating System is Fedora 16, is it is possible to install Qt5 ?

Comment: Sorry I do not know, since I have never used fedora, but do try to install it. It should work

Answer (score 6):

my usual starting point to investigate which software is installed is with

```
dpkg -l | grep "what I am looking for"
```

you should get a list of installed packages. Then with

```
dpkg -L "packagename" # (or whatever your package manager is)
```

you get a list of installed files for that package

Comment: ...Or check with whatever other package manager your Linux distro comes with (pacman, rpm, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Python:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
print(QtCore.qVersion())
```

If you're using C++:

```
#include <QtGlobal>
std::cout << qVersion();
```

Answer (score 3):

For qt4 :

```
QT_SELECT=4 qmake -v
```

for qt5 :

```
QT_SELECT=5 qmake -v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use qmake -query QT_VERSION:

```
➜  ~ qmake -query QT_VERSION
4.8.7

➜  ~ Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake -query QT_VERSION
5.15.0

➜  ~ qt-6.0.0/bin/qmake -query QT_VERSION
6.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

On terminal,`qtchooser --l` is another way to see the installed instances.
The print-out may look like this :

```
4  
5  
default  
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu  
qt4  
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu  
qt5
```