# Problems when binding PyQt5 library using Python SIP

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-sip

I'm currently trying to integrate my C++ Qt5 library in Python using sip based on [this tutorial](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/examples.html) (section "Using a Real Library").

However, I'm having some problems with the Qt5 sip files when I run `sip-install` or `python -m pip install .`

**Edit:**
I found out that i can find the qt bindings in my virtual environment folder: venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/bindings/
Therefore I tried to set up a fresh virtualenv, install PyQt5 and use this path for sip-include-dirs. But I'm still getting an error:

```
_in_process.py: /.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/bindings/QtCore/QtCore.toml: 'QtCore' was built against ABI v12.11 but this module is being built against ABI v12.8
```

Also different versions of PyQt5 and defining sip-abi-version or abi-version in the .toml does not seem to change anything (except that sometimes the /.../bindings folder is empty)
What am I doing wrong?

**Previous problem description:**

Following errors are printed:

```
/usr/share/sip/PyQt5/QtCore/qglobal.sip: line 114: column 5: 'Qt::KeyboardModifiers::__hash__' must return a Py_hash_t
/usr/share/sip/PyQt5/QtCore/qglobal.sip: line 114: column 5: 'Qt::MouseButtons::__hash__' must return a Py_hash_t
/usr/share/sip/PyQt5/QtCore/qglobal.sip: line 114: column 5: 'Qt::Orientations::__hash__' must return a Py_hash_t
/usr/share/sip/PyQt5/QtCore/qglobal.sip: line 114: column 5: 'Qt::Alignment::__hash__' must return a Py_hash_t

... and about a hundred more of the same kind ...
```

Probably this is some kind of version incompatibility here. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my setup:

[Qt and python version:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058718/how-to-find-version-of-qt)

```
$ python
Python 3.8.0 (default, Dec  9 2021, 17:53:27) [GCC 8.4.0] on linux ...
PYQT_VERSION_STR = 5.15.9 ...
QT_VERSION_STR = 5.15.2 ...
```

Sip version:

```
$ sip-install --version
6.7.11

$ sip -V
4.19.7   <<<??? This installation appears to be different from the one I did using python -m pip install sip. Is this one active? python -m pip install . works, even if I do python -m pip uninstall sip
```

Other libs versions:

```
qtbase5-dev is version (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6).
qtdeclarative5-dev is version (5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1).
```

Those last two were missing and I had to install them manually

My little test project is very similar to the one in the tutorial, except I include and derive from Qt widgets and include sip-include-dirs to tell sip where to find the Qt sip files:

pyproject.toml:

```
# Specify sip v6 as the build system for the package.
[build-system]
requires = ["sip >=6, <7"]
build-backend = "sipbuild.api"

# Specify the PEP 566 metadata for the project.
[tool.sip.metadata]
name = "MyProject"

[tool.sip.project]
sip-include-dirs = ["/usr/share/sip/PyQt5/"]

# Configure the building of the fib bindings.
[tool.sip.bindings.MyProject]
headers = ["mywidgets/mywidget.hpp"]
include-dirs = ["/.../my_lib_project/src/"]
libraries = ["mylib"]
library-dirs = ["/.../my_lib_project/build/"]
```

MyProject.sip:

```
%Module(name=MyProject, language="C++")

%Import QtCore/QtCoremod.sip
%Import QtWidgets/QtWidgetsmod.sip

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
%TypeHeaderCode
#include "mywidgets/mywidget.hpp"
%End
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent);

};
```

Comment: You are touching an undocumented feature. You should understand internal build system of PyQt. The starting point is reverse-engineering the ```project.py``` in the source distribution. In the old days, a few hackers did this, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261684/1186624). But AFAIK, there is no such trial these days.